# Составить условие в PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt, qtableview

Возле каждого больного будет кнопка **`Выселить`**, с помощью нажатия которой можно будет выселить больного из палаты при выписке, что вычеркнет его имя из базы данных больных, чтобы освободить место.

Распределение больных будет происходить по возрасту, на две возрастные категории:

- *18-45* лет
- *46+*:

В каждой палате будет высчитываться средний возраст пациентов, и, при наличии свободных мест, пациенты из возрастной группы *18-45* будут селиться в палаты со средним возрастом ниже *45*, а пациенты из возрастной группы *46+* будут распределены в палаты со средним возрастом пациентов выше *45*, но только при наличии свободных мест в подобных палатах.

При отсутствии вариантов размещения пациентов по возрасту, они будут заселены на любые свободные кровати в палатах, соответствующих их полу, но при наличии свободных кроватей.

При отсутствии свободных мест вообще, пациенты будут размещены в коридоре, о чём появится соответствующее сообщение:

> *«Свободных мест нет. Пациент (данные пациента) будет поселён в холле»*.

Список пациентов, размещённых в холле, будет выводиться в каждом отделении ниже списка палат с подписью

> *«Временное размещение (холл)»*

в формате, подобном списку пациентов в палате, но вместо кнопки *«Выселить»* будет кнопка *«Поселить в палату»*, с помощью которой можно будет поселить пациента в палату вместо холла, выбрав вручную номер освободившийся палаты, куда допустимо переселить больного.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, \
    QTableView, QGridLayout, QListWidget, QLabel, QListView, QTabWidget, QFrame, \
    QHeaderView, QFormLayout                                                        # +++
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.table = QTableView(self)
        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Имя", "Пол", "Возраст", "Отделение", "Диагноз", "Палата"])

        self.table.setAlternatingRowColors(True)                                    # +
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(4, QHeaderView.Stretch)  # +

        self.btn = QPushButton("Отправить")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.add)

        self.years = QLabel('Возраст', alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.years.setMaximumWidth(60)
        self.years_line = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Введите возраст...')
        self.diagnose_line = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Введите диагноз...')
        self.diagnose = QLabel('Диагноз', alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.otd_line = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Введите отделение...')
        self.otd = QLabel('Отделение', alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.gender_line = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Введите пол...')
        self.gender = QLabel('Пол', alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.name_line = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Введите имя...')
        self.name = QLabel('Имя', alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.init()

    def init(self):
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.name, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.name_line, 1, 1, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.gender, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.gender_line, 2, 1, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.years, 3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.years_line, 3, 1, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.otd, 4, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.otd_line, 4, 1, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.diagnose, 5, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.diagnose_line, 5, 1, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.btn, 6, 1, 1, 3) #, 1, -10)
        grid.addWidget(self.table, 7, 0, 5, 4)

def add(self):
    p = 45
    i = 0
    rows = self.model.rowCount()
    columns = self.model.columnCount()
    for column in range(columns):
        if column == 0:
            self.model.setItem(rows, column, QStandardItem(self.name_line.text()))
        if column == 1:
            self.model.setItem(rows, column, QStandardItem(self.gender_line.text()))
        if column == 2:
            self.model.setItem(rows, column, QStandardItem(self.years_line.text()))
        if column == 3:
            self.model.setItem(rows, column, QStandardItem(self.otd_line.text()))
        if column == 4:
            self.model.setItem(rows, column, QStandardItem(self.diagnose_line.text()))
        if column == 5:
            if self.years_line <= p:
                self.table.item(self.model.index(i, 5), "1")
        if column == 6:
            self.table.setIndexWidget(self.model.index(i, 6), self.del_btn)

        self.name_line.clear()
        self.diagnose_line.clear()
        self.otd_line.clear()
        self.years_line.clear()
        self.gender_line.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    ex = Example()
    ex.resize(700, 500)
    ex.setWindowTitle('Больница')
    ex.setWindowIcon(QIcon('key.png'))
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: так а в чем проблема, у вас не получается составить условие?

Comment: да, не понимаю как это осуществить

Comment: а куда селить, если в обоих палатах совпадают возрастные группы?

Comment: лучше будет сделать строгое селение <= 45 в одну, больше - в другую. И только если мест нет селить в противоположную. Тогда при поступлении нового, делаете запрос в базу, смотрите возраст, и в зависимости от него и наличия мест селите куда надо - хранить можно словарем - номер палаты, кол-во пациентов и свободных мест. Что касается условия - тут все просто: проверка на возраст, а вследствие проверка на наличие мест, если нет - селить к другим, если нет вообще - в коридор. Тогда при выселении можно еще проверять количество тех, кто ждет в коридоре, если они есть - заселить того, кто ждет первым

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что у меня никак не получается это реализовать в коде, не могу понять как создать такое условие в модели, как экспортировать это в файл, хотя это малая из бед и как засунуть кнопку УДАЛИТЬ в QtableView

Comment: первая работа в PyQt5 и с хранением в бд

Comment: ну кнопку отправить же в как то засунули) я бы порекомендовал воспользоваться sqlite, очень удобно, благодаря нему как раз таки и можно реализовать запросы в базу, загрузку\выгрузку, сохранение данных в переменную для дальнейшего обращения и тд.

Comment: к сожалению, безуспешно

Comment: ''' if column == 5:
                if self.years_line <= int(45):
                    self.model.setItem(rows, column, QStandardItem(palata))
            if column == 6:
                self.table.setIndexWidget(self.model.index(i, 6), self.del_btn) '''              Добавил кнопку Удалить но с условием все не получается

Comment: ой нене, только без кода в комментариях, если что - дополняйте в вопросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы задаете очень глобальные вопросы, это не очень хорошо.

Я слабо разбираюсь в медицине и поэтому не понимаю, для чего нужно размещать пациентов в палаты по возрасту ?

Я увидел вашу задачу так:

- некоторые поля превратились из `QLineEdit` в `QComboBox`
- `Возраст` превратился в `Дата рождения` - `QDateEdit со встроенным календарем`!
- открыл мини-больницу в виде словаря `listPalat`
- таблице у вас появилась возможность `сортировать данные`!
- `редактировать` в таблице можно только полк `Диагноз`!
- добавил действия по нажатию кнопки `Выписать`
- добавил действия по нажатию кнопки `Поселить в палату`

Попробуйте.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, palats):                                        # + palats
        super().__init__()

        self.palats = palats

        self.table = QTableView(self)
        self.table.doubleClicked.connect(self.onDoubleClick)
        self.table.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)  # +++
        self.table.setSortingEnabled(True)                                      # +++
        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.table.setModel(self.model)

        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Имя", "Пол", "Возраст", "Отделение", "Диагноз", "Палата"])
        self.table.setAlternatingRowColors(True)  
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(4, QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.btn_reg = QPushButton("Зарегистрировать")
        self.btn_reg.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.btn_vip = QPushButton("Выписать")                                   # +++
        self.btn_vip.clicked.connect(self.vip)
        self.btn_pere = QPushButton("Поселить в палату")                         # +++
        self.btn_pere.clicked.connect(self.pere)

        self.name = QLabel('Имя', alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.name_line = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Введите имя...')

        self.gender = QLabel('Пол', alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)        
        self.cb_gender = QtWidgets.QComboBox()                                 # QComboBox
        self.cb_gender.addItems(["ж", "м"])

        self.years = QLabel('Дата рождения', alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.years.setMaximumWidth(80)
        self.date = QDateEdit()                                                # QDateEdit
        self.date.setCalendarPopup(True)                                       # + setCalendarPopup 

        self.otd = QLabel('Отделение', alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.cb_otd = QtWidgets.QComboBox()                                    # QComboBox
        self.cb_otd.addItems(["Терапевтическое", "Хирургическое", 
                              "Кардиохирургическое", "Травматологическое"])

        self.diagnose_line = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Введите диагноз...')
        self.diagnose = QLabel('Диагноз', alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)

        self.init()

    def init(self):
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.name, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.name_line, 1, 1, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.gender, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.cb_gender, 2, 1, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.years, 3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.date, 3, 1, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.otd, 4, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.cb_otd, 4, 1, 1, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.diagnose, 5, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.diagnose_line, 5, 1, 1, 3)

        grid.addWidget(self.btn_reg, 6, 1)  
        grid.addWidget(self.btn_vip, 6, 2) 
        grid.addWidget(self.btn_pere, 6, 3) 

        grid.addWidget(self.table, 7, 0, 5, 4)

    def add(self):
        rows = self.model.rowCount()
        if not self.name_line.text():
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'ВНИМАНИЕ !', 'Заполните данные пациента.')
            return

        pl = ''
        if self.cb_gender.currentText() == 'ж':
            for palata, list_mest in self.palats['0'].items():
                for i, v in enumerate(list_mest):
                    if v == ' ':
                        self.palats['0'][palata][i] = self.name_line.text()
                        pl = palata
                        break
                if pl: break
            if not pl:
                for palata, list_mest in self.palats['2'].items():
                    for i, v in enumerate(list_mest):
                        if v[0] == ' ':                                             
                            self.palats['2'][palata][i][0] = self.name_line.text()  
                            self.palats['2'][palata][i][1] = '0'                    
                            pl = palata
                            break
        elif self.cb_gender.currentText() == 'м':
            for palata, list_mest in self.palats['1'].items():
                for i, v in enumerate(list_mest):
                    if v == ' ':
                        self.palats['1'][palata][i] = self.name_line.text()
                        pl = palata
                        break
                if pl: break
            if not pl:
                for palata, list_mest in self.palats['2'].items():
                    for i, v in enumerate(list_mest):
                        if v[0] == ' ':
                            self.palats['2'][palata][i][0] = self.name_line.text()
                            self.palats['2'][palata][i][1] = '1'                    
                            pl = palata
                            break

        if not pl:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'ВНИМАНИЕ !', 
                  f'Нет свободных мест для <b>{self.cb_gender.currentText()}</b>.<br>Надо кого-то выписывать!')
        else:
            self.model.setItem(rows, 0, QStandardItem(self.name_line.text()))
            self.model.setItem(rows, 1, QStandardItem(self.cb_gender.currentText()))
            self.model.setItem(rows, 2, QStandardItem(self.date.date().toString("dd.MM.yyyy")))
            self.model.setItem(rows, 3, QStandardItem(self.cb_otd.currentText()))
            self.model.setItem(rows, 4, QStandardItem(self.diagnose_line.text()))
            self.model.setItem(rows, 5, QStandardItem(pl)) 

        self.name_line.clear()
        self.diagnose_line.clear()
        self.name_line.setFocus()                                   # +


    def onDoubleClick(self, index):                                 # +++
        if index.column() == 4:
            self.table.setEditTriggers(QTableView.DoubleClicked | QTableView.EditKeyPressed)
        else:
            self.table.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)

    def vip(self):
        idx = self.table.currentIndex()
        if idx.row() == -1:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'ВНИМАНИЕ !', 'Выберите пациента для выписки.')
            return

        name = self.table.model().item(idx.row(), 0).text() 
        if QMessageBox.question(self, 'ВНИМАНИЕ !', 
                f"Вы уверены, что хотите выписать <b>{name}</b> ?") == QMessageBox.Yes:
            pl = self.table.model().item(idx.row(), 5).text()
            gender_ = self.table.model().item(idx.row(), 1).text()

            if pl == 'Холл':
                gender = '0' if gender_ == 'ж' else '1'
                ii = self.palats['2'][pl].index([name, gender])          
                self.palats['2'][pl][ii] = [' ', ' ']
            else:
                gender = '0' if (pl == 'Палата1' or pl == 'Палата2') else '1' 
                ii = self.palats[gender][pl].index(name)          
                self.palats[gender][pl][ii] = ' '

            self.model.removeRow(idx.row())
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'ВНИМАНИЕ !', 
                  f'Пациент <b>{name}</b> - выписан из палаты <b>{pl}</b>.')

    def pere(self):
        k_m_x = [ i for i in self.palats['2']['Холл'] if i[0] != ' ' ]
        if not k_m_x:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'ВНИМАНИЕ !', 
                  f'Пациентов для переселкния из Холлa - <b>Нет</b>.')
            return

        for name, gender in k_m_x:    # Холл
            fl_break = False
            for pl, lm in self.palats[gender].items():        
                for i, m in enumerate(lm):
                    if m == ' ':
                        self.palats[gender][pl][i] = name

                        ii = self.palats['2']['Холл'].index([name, gender])
                        self.palats['2']['Холл'][ii] = [' ', ' ']

                        rows = self.model.rowCount()
                        for r in range(rows):
                            if self.table.model().item(r, 0).text() == name:
                                self.model.setItem(r, 5, QStandardItem(pl))
                                fl_break = True
                                break
                    if fl_break: break
                if fl_break: break    


# Какое-то небольшое отделение больницы
listPalat = {
    '0':{                                     # ж
        'Палата1': [' ', ' ',],
        'Палата2': [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    },
    '1':{                                     # м
        'Палата3': [' ', ' ', ' '],
        'Палата4': [' ', ' ', ' '],
    },
    '2':{
        'Холл': [[' ', ' '], [' ', ' '], [' ', ' '], [' ', ' '], [' ', ' '], [' ', ' ']],
    },
}            


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    default_font = QFont("Times", 11, QFont.Bold)
    app.setFont(default_font)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    ex = Example(listPalat)                                  # + listPalat
    ex.resize(700, 500)
    ex.setWindowTitle('Больница')
    ex.setWindowIcon(QIcon('key.png'))
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: очень вам благодарен